# item not adding to array with the .push() fucntion

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using react and trying to add a new number to the array inside my functional component, but is only returns the new number and deletes the previous ones?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DashboardHeader from '../dashboardHeader/dashboardHeader'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function EmptyInvoice() {
    // setting local state 
    const [uniqueID, setuniqueID] = useState(1)
    let invoiceRows = [0]
    // function to ensure that every row is a unique number
    function customNumberGenerator(){
        setuniqueID(uniqueID + 1)
        invoiceRows.push(uniqueID)
    }
    // array of amout of items on an invoice
    const invoiceItems = [{number: 1}]
    console.log(invoiceRows)
    return(
        <div className='float-right' onClick={() => {customNumberGenerator()}}>
            add item
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where is `setuniqueID()` and other functions?? Can you post a working example.

Comment: please add all missing parts as well.

Comment: *"only returns the new number and deletes the previous ones"* Where exactly? Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create new array each time your render function executed.
You should use `useState` for `invoiceRows` too like this:

```
const [ uniqueID, setuniqueID ] = useState(1);
const [ invoiceRows, setInvoicesRows ] = useState([0]);

// function to ensure that every row is a unique number
function customNumberGenerator() {
    setuniqueID(uniqueID + 1);
    setInvoicesRows([...invoiceRows, uniqueID])
}

// array of amout of items on an invoice
const invoiceItems = [ { number: 1 } ];
console.log(invoiceRows);
```

Comment: I forgot about the fact that it renders a new array. The second state fixed the issue. Great insight and explanation,  thanks!